# Strip text from files after first space

Tags: python, glob, file-rename

I'm trying to rename about a few thousand files to just have their code, files are named like this:

> 2834 The file
>
> 2312 The file
>
> 982 The file

Desired output:

> 2834
>
> 2312
>
> 982

The code I want to rename them to is separated by a space, so I just need to strip the text after the space.

I have tried using os/glob/enumerate just to rename in them in numerical order, which is proving problematic as the directory is not being returned in the same order, so when I rename them the codes are mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `glob` and `os`. A simple example (with comments), is as follows:

```
import glob
import os

# iterate over all the files
for files in glob.glob('*.*'):
    try:
        new = files.replace("The file", '') # if there's a match replace names
        os.rename(files, new) # rename the file
        print files, new # just to make sure it's working
    except:
        print 'ERROR!!,', files # to see if there were any errors
```

Alternatively, if the the code is always the first 4 characters, you could do the following:

```
import glob
import os

# iterate over all the files
for files in glob.glob('*.*'):
    try:
        os.rename(files, files[0:4]) # rename the file
        print files, new # just to make sure it's working
    except:
        print 'ERROR!!,', files # to see if there were any errors
```

Just noticed one of your examples only has 3 characters as the code. A better solution might be using `.find(' ')` on the file name to locate the space ready for the string slice. For example:

```
import glob
import os

# iterate over all the files
for files in glob.glob('*.*'):
    try:
        os.rename(files, files[0: files.find(' ')]) # rename the file
        print files # just to make sure it's working
    except:
        print 'ERROR!!,', files # to see if there were any errors
```

Comment: Yep the updated answer seems to be what I'm after! Only one problem they are all printing error. That's because I didn't specify these are jpgs and pngs?

Comment: updated answer - it's because we left `new` in there - just remove that. I've tested it and it's working fine

Comment: Thank you! Still seems to be removing the file extension, but as a quick fix I've just added .jpg to the end of them all as in this case it doesn't matter if it's jpg or png!

Comment: Cool - just use `extension = files[-3:]` to access the extension and then write that back in. Please accept answer if you are happy

Answer (score 3):

Others already demonstrated how to do it. So I'll just suggest better way to get the first word in a string:

```
filename = "12345 blahblahblah"
sfn = filename.split(" ", 1)
newfilename = sfn[0]
```

This way if the string doesn't contain " " nothing will happen i.e. the same string will be returned.
Using find(), on the other hand, will return -1 if " " is not found. And, slicing filename[0:-1] would take the last character off, which may be undesirable effect. Both will result in an empty string if first character is " ". So I propose even better solution:

```
filename = " 12345 blahblahblah"
sfn = filename.split(None, 1)
newfilename = sfn[0]
```

If some other separator than a whitespace is desired then it would be:

```
filename = "____12345_blahblahblah"
sfn = [x for x in filename.split("_") if x!=""]
newfilename = sfn[0]
```

This then would be complete renamer for you. It keeps the extension and respects full paths as well.

```
import os

def RenameToFirstWord (filename):
    filename = os.path.abspath(filename)
    origfn = filename
    path, filename = os.path.split(filename)
    fn, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    # If filename starts with extension separator (hidden files on *nixes):
    if not fn: fn = ext; ext = ""
    sfn = fn.split(None, 1)
    newfn = sfn[0]+ext
    try:
        os.rename(origfn, os.path.join(path, newfn))
    except Exception, e:
        print "Cannot rename '%s' to '%s'!\nError is: '%s'\nand it is ignored!" % (filename, newfn, str(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `glob.glob()` to get a full list of files (I recommend giving it a full path). Next filter only the files with a `.png` or `.jpg` extension. Next extract all the numbers using a regular expression. If there are multiple groups it takes just the first group of digits.

Lastly, create the new filename and use `os.rename()` to rename the file:

```
import glob
import os
import re

for filename in glob.glob(r'c:\my folder\*.*'):
    path, name = os.path.split(filename)
    extension = os.path.splitext(name)[1]

    if extension.lower() in ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg']:
        digits = re.findall('(\d+)', name)

        if digits:
            new_filename = os.path.join(path, '{}{}'.format(digits[0], extension))
            print "{:30} {}".format(filename, new_filename)     # show what is being renamed
            os.rename(filename, new_filename)
```

So for example:

```
2834 The file.jpg       2834.jpg
2312 The file.PNG       2312.PNG
982 The file.jpg        982.jpg
1234 test 4567.jpg      1234.jpg
The file 7133123.png    7133123.png
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Although when I run this it adds 2017_ to the start of the file name? Also, fort instances like this `1234 test 4567.jpg      1234_4567.jpg` I would just like `1234.jpg`?

Comment: Hopefully the digits you have result in unique filenames, otherwise there may be an exception raised when trying to rename them. I have updated the script to only use the first group of digits.

Comment: Thankfully I know they are unique! It seems to be trying to rename the files as 2017 though? It renames one 2017 then throwing `FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: a\b\c\x.jpg -> a\b\c\2017.jpg `

Comment: `x.jpg` would not be renamed though as there are no digits in it. Are you sure your indenting is correct?

Comment: Sorry I meant x as an example. They all start with a numerical code, followed by a space, followed by the string I want to exclude

Comment: I double checked the indenting, it all looks fine. I then removed the one file it had previously renamed as 2017. Ran the code again but the same thing happened. I.e. it renamed one file as 2017 then threw `WinError 183`

Comment: It means there is now an existing file with the same name in that folder.

Comment: The print statement should tell you which file is being renamed being it does it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155752/discussion-between-maverick-and-martin-evans).